# How to install monaco font in webstorm

Tags: 14.04, fonts

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS,

I am new to ubuntu and webstorm, I want to install monaco font in webstorm, so I installed monaco font in my system using this command

```
curl -kL https://raw.github.com/cstrap/monaco-font/master/install-font-ubuntu.sh | bash
```

font installed on `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/custom` location

But when I try to select this font via webstorm, monaco font not listed under settings->Editor->colors&fonts->fonts